# Why does "for letter in line" works, while if "word=line.strip()", "for letter in word" does'nt work . **String search**in file**

Tags: python, python-3.x

The target was to bring in a certain str inputs, which have same letters for different words.While I have narrowed down the accuracy percentage. I'm unable to figure out a few problems.

Link to file : http://www.gutenberg.org/files/3201/files/

```
fln=open('CROSSWD.TXT')

def uses_only(allow,word1,count,count_2):
    y=0 #I've tried assigning line before loop as line=fln.readlines() does'nt work
    for line in fln:
        word=line.strip() # somehow the line is stripped of white spaces here or there
        for letter in line: # Does'nt work for in word
            x=count
            z=count_2
            if letter in allow:
                count+=1
            elif letter not in allow: # break loop for unwanted letters
                count=0
                count_2+=1
                break
            
        if x==len(word) and len(allow)==len(word): # runs if the letters match
            y+=x/len(word)
            word1+=word+','
    return True,word1,int(y) #returns matching words & word count

def run():
    allow=input('Enter the only letters the word must contain : ') # input from user         
    word1=''
    count=0
    count_2=0
    print(uses_only(allow,word1,count,count_2))          
run()
```

The main problem i'm facing is in

```
    for letter in line:
```

If I use

```
    for letter in word: **# What's making the loop to break?**
```

it return an empty string, While they're supposed to do the same thing a little concised in the

```
    word=line.strip()
```

Also kindly help me to bring the match to be more accurate

**Input : eat**

**current output :**

```
(True, 'ate,eat,eta,tae,tat,tea,tee,', 7)
```

***The output gives the words with matching str taken as input for same length & the No. of words that match.***

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: I'm not sure how the code is supposed to work, but my guess is that the newline at the end of the unstripped line is accidentally making the code work by breaking out of the loop. So if you strip the line, it's not taking the break path and count doesn't get reset.

Comment: "The target was to bring in a certain str inputs, which have same letters for different words.While I have narrowed down the accuracy percentage. I'm unable to figure out a few problems." I have no idea what this is supposed to mean. Could you show an example of how to run the program, and *exactly* what is supposed to happen as a result, and show how the output relates to the input?

Comment: Have updated for the Input & output samples.

Comment: Your `elif` statement is not necessary.  A simple `else` will suffice.  (The logical expression is redundant.)

Comment: @RufusVS. I'm using  `elif ` to **reset the counter to 0** when loop comes across unwanted words. To get count count of words that actually match with data.

Comment: *Why* do you only reset `count` when you come across an unwanted character? (And what's the point of `z` and `count_2`?

Comment: Also, RufusVS's point was that an `else` would do the same thing as your `elif letter not in allow`.

Comment: @user2357112 supports Monica. I've been using more variables to trim down acuraccy. `z` and `count_2` are not required in the current code. `count` returns count of Strings that match. Likewise trying to implement`count_2` **to get count of strings that don't match**. The only thing bugging me is **why does `for letter in word:` not work?**

Comment: You only reset `count` when you hit the line break at the end of the line. `word` doesn't have the line break.

Comment: @user2357112 supports Monica. **Line break is not the problem**. since `count` is updated every time I hit the desired or undesired letter. The **problem lied in where the count was updated** as mentioned by @Jailton Silva in the Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging the code I realized that the error is in the fact that using 'word' the variables x and z are not updated in the last loop, just put them at the end of the for loop:

```
for letter in word:  # Now work for in word
    if letter in allow:
        count+=1
    elif letter not in allow: # break loop for unwanted letters
        count=0
        count_2+=1
        break
    x=count
    z=count_2
```

Comment: That Helped Thanks. So, the count was not updated for the final iteration. So, x became redundant in the final iteration returning count=0 & making it return a empty string & count=0. I get it now.

Comment: This is reducing the accuracy of the return argument, providing words not necessary. Have come up with a valid method. Will provide the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to overcome this problem I took the `for letter in word` into a **separate function**. This solves both the iteration problem & the accuracy of the string match.

```
fln=open('CROSSWD.TXT')
def test_word(word,allow): # Test for a sinlgle word in a line
    for letter in word:
        if letter not in allow:
            return False
    return True
def use_only():
    count=0
    allow=input('Enter the letters: ')
    word1=''
    for line in fln: # iteration for no. of loops
        word=line.strip()
        if test_word(word,allow)==True: #verify the match
            word1+=word+','
            count+=1
    return word1, count
use_only()
```

In : `letter`

Out : `('eel,el,ell,er,ere,err,et,lee,leer,leet,let,letter,letterer,re,ree,reel,reeler,relet,reletter,ret,rete,retell,tee,teeter,tele,tell,teller,terete,terret,tetter,tree,tret,', 32)`